# Calling Page_Load on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it a good practice to call Page_Load function in another function like this. It's working but I don't know if i should do this

```
public bool myButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
Page_Load(this, null);
}
```

Comment: If this is a duplicate I'm sorry, I didn't find original question.

Comment: This indicates a bad software architecture. General functions should be implemented in well named methods, to make your code clearer and better reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you shouldn't. And it is very easy to prevent this:

In your `Page_Load`, call a method that does the actual work in the method now. Then call that method from `myButtonClick`:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SomeMethod();
}

public void myButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SomeMethod();
}

private void SomeMethod()
{
    // the actual code now in Page_Load
}
```

You see, nice and clean and reusable too.